# How can I rewrite the pemutations programe become a combination programe?

Tags: elisp

every one,I wanna rewrite a pumutation pro,make it become a 
combination pro,any idear?
for example,input list '(1 2 2)
pumutation become ((1 2 2) (1 2 2) (2 1 2) (2 2 1) (2 1 2) (2 2 1))
i want it become ((1 2 2) (2 1 2) (2 2 1) )

(defun test-company--permutations (lst)
  (if (not lst)
      '(nil)
    (cl-mapcan
     (lambda (e)
       (mapcar (lambda (perm) (cons e perm))
               (test-company--permutations (cl-remove e lst :count 1))))
     lst)))
(test-company--permutations '(1 2 2))

Answer (score 0):

```lisp
(defun test-company--permutations (lst)
  (if (not lst)
      '(nil)
    (cl-mapcan
     (lambda (e)
       (mapcar (lambda (perm) (cons e perm))
               (test-company--permutations (cl-remove e lst :count 1))))
     lst)))
```

```lisp
(test-company--permutations '(1 2 2))
```